# maven versions:set not taking the version form the version.properties

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

If i used mvn versions:set -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=${versioninversion.properties} in script it asked for **Enter the new version to set DEV.0.0-SNAPSHOT:** i manually enter the value, it doesn't taken form the version.properties file

I have a file **version.properties** inside the project.
in that file have below entries.

> projectversion=1.0.34
>
> xxxxversion= [1.0.26]
>
> YYYYVersion=67.8.0

now i given as

> mvn versions:set -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
> -DnewVersion=${**projectversion**}

I write a script(bat) file as below

```
cd X-Folder
call mvn versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DparentVersion=${YYYYVersion}
call mvn versions:update-property -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -Dproperty=xyz-schemas.version -DnewVersion=${xxxxversion}
call mvn versions:set -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=${projectversion}
call mvn clean install
cd ..
```

First two mvn commands executed successfully.
While executing 3 rd MVN command ,
It asks for Enter the new version to set DEV.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
Its not taking from version.properties For first two its taking from the version.properties

Comment: What should `${versioninversion.properties}` mean? I don't understand what you are trying to reference?

Comment: I actually doubt that any of the `mvn` calls work. How should Maven get the property values from the `version.properties`. Where did you specify this file? How do you import it?

Comment: I didn't specify the file any where, but versions:update-property is working and taking from the file, it replaces the place holder as value from version.properties, but version :set not taking from the file. The version.proeprties just i kept the file in side the maven project.

Comment: So when you remove the version.properties file and start the bat file, it behaves differently?

Comment: It takes form the maven latest of that component.

Comment: I never heard of a Maven mechanism which simply works by calling a file "version.properties". Maybe it exists. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: In jenkins job we configure like that, but in that we have a option to configure the versions.properties and it takes form the file, but am wondering how the place holder works in my normal script.